# Bootstrap columns overlap if screen size is reduced

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, height, row

I have a Bootstrap grid set up like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="img/photo1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="img/photo2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="img/photo3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="img/photo4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="img/photo5.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My first column spans over 2 rows and 2 columns, and then I have 4 images on the right spanning over 1 row and 1 column each.

It looks fine until I reduce the browser width. Then the second column containing 4 small images overlap the first column.

I'd really appreciate any advice on how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u set up a fiddle??

Comment: I figured out the issue while setting up a fiddle... I apparently had the position of the first column img set as absolute. Will check my code more carefully next time before posting!